# Checking file existence in Bash using commandline argument

Tags: bash

How do you use a command line argument as a file path and check for file existence in Bash?

I have the simple Bash script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
echo "arg1=$1"
if [ ! -f "$1" ]
then
    echo "File $1 does not exist."
    exit 1
fi
echo "File exists!"
```

and in the same directory, I have a `data` folder containing `stuff.txt`.

If I run `./test.sh data/stuff.txt` I see the expected output:

```
arg1=data/stuff.txt
"File exists!"
```

However, if I call this script from a second script `test2.sh`, in the same directory, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
fn="data/stuff.txt"
./test.sh $fn
```

I get the mangled output:

```
arg1=data/stuff.txt
 does not exist
```

Why does the call work when I run it manually from a terminal, but not when I run it through another Bash script, even though both are receiving the same file path? What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The filename does not have spaces. Both scripts are executable. I'm running this on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: So long as `fn` does NOT contain whitespace, you should be okay, but it would more properly be called as `./test.sh "$fn"`.

Comment: Of course, if `./test.sh` is not executable (e.g. `chmod +x test.sh`), then it will not do anything and you will get funny output (like permission denied). Without making it executable, you would need `bash ./test.sh "$fn"`. (otherwise, there is nothing wrong with what you are doing)

Comment: add some debugging statements like `echo "\$@=[$@]"; echo "PWD=$PWD"`. I'm betting your `PWD` changes between your two invocation methods. You can also test with a fully qualified path to file, i.e. `/home/userName/data/File.txt` (note the initial `/` char. ). Good luck.

Comment: It looks to me like your second script has DOS/Windows-style line endings, which causes all sorts of weird problems. See: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: This is weird, because in my PC your code works well. Just for your info, I used bash terminal.

Comment: agree with  @GordonDavisson  , the output of second script " does not exist" is weird comparing with first script , and likely caused by unexpected ```\r```

Comment: @bigdataolddriver An extra whitespace character was my suspicion too. I also noticed that the path is 14 characters, but if I print out the length of `$1` inside `test.sh`, it says it's 15. Where is that extra character coming from and how do I remove it? If there is an extra `\r` character in it, why does the filename print out correctly as arg1 echo line?

Comment: the ```\r``` affects every char appears  between itself and next ```\n```   . use ```vim -b test2.sh``` to see if there is any ```^M``` showing up in vim,  or use ```od  -c test2.sh```  dump to console, you would see  ```\r```  printed if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

The filename was getting an extra whitespace character added to it as a result of how I was retrieving it in my second script. I didn't note this in my question, but I was retrieving the filename from folder list over SSH, like:

```
fn=$(ssh -t "cd /project/; ls -t data | head -n1" | head -n1)
```

Essentially, I wanted to get the filename of the most recent file in a directory on a remote server. Apparently, `head` includes the trailing newline character. I fixed it by changing it to:

```
fn=$(ssh -t "cd /project/; ls -t data | head -n1" | head -n1 | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '\r')
```

Thanks to @bigdataolddriver for hinting at the problem likely being an extra character.